# Why does PHP print ISO date with leading 0.00000000

Tags: php, mongodb, date, timestamp, iso

I have ISO dates stored in MongoDB.

```
> db.myDB.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "time" : ISODate("2014-08-05T11:18:55Z) }
```

When I echo it in PHP, it displays it differently from the database.

```
echo $document["time"] // Prints 0.00000000 1407236935
```

What's up with the zeros? What format is it printing it in? Is there a format I can use that will print more nicely, so a human could determine it with precision to the minute?

Comment: Because you are ehcoing the string representation of that object, try accessing the sec propery of the class: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Date objects

The MongoDB PHP driver uses the [`MongoDate`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) class to represent date objects.

If you inspect the contents of your variable with:

```
var_dump($document["time"])
```

... you'll see the internal class properties:

```
object(MongoDate)#7 (2) {
   ["sec"]=>
   int(1407299400)
   ["usec"]=>
   int(313000)
}
```

.. which, as you discovered, [stringify](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodate.tostring.php) to a pair of integers similar to [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) if you try to `echo()` a MongoDate object:

```
0.31300000 1407299400
```

### Formatting a `MongoDate`

To format as "human readable" you can pass the MongoDate value (in seconds) to the standard PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
 echo date('F j, Y g:i a', $document["time"]->sec), "\n";
```

.. which should output similar to:

```
 August 6, 2014 2:30 pm
```